# How to show Timestamp from Firebase Realtime Database on Xcode in UiTableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, firebase, timestamp

Alrighty this ones a tough. I'm building a social media app with a feed that has a Uitableview that is being stored in the firebase realtime database the posts contain

author
 text: "hi"
 timestamp: "1532194221795"

My goal is to present this timestamp in my cells in a bit more attractive way for example (15 min ago, 2 hrs ago, 5 days ago, 2 months ago) according to when the cell was posted.

I have this in my NewPostViewController
`"timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]`

Saved as a double in my feed like this `let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {`

and its shown on table by my PostTableViewCell `subtitleLabel.text = "\(post.timestamp)"`

I also have gathered information like this

`func timeSinceNowString() -> String
    {
        let calendar = Calendar.current

```
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self, to: Date())

    if components.day! >= 365 {
        return "\(components.day! / 365) years ago"
    }

    if components.day! >= 7 {
        return "\(components.day! / 7) weeks ago"
    }

    if components.day! > 0 {
        return "\(components.day!) days ago"
    }
    else if components.hour! > 0 {
        return "\(components.hour!) hours ago"
    }
    else if components.minute! > 0 {
        return "\(components.minute!) minutes ago"
    }
    return "Now"
}
```

`and this too`Date(timeIntervalSince1970: createdAt / 1000)`

its giving me errors like type of expression is ambiguous without more context" for the first part and  "use of unresolved indentifier 'createdAt'"for the date second part. Does anyone know how to set this up without these errors? I will love you forever, Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

just change those `createdAt` with `timestamp` which you already typecasted to `Double`.

This is my playground:

```
func timeSinceNowString(_ timeInterval:TimeInterval) -> String {

    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval/1000), to: Date())

    guard let days = components.day, let hours = components.hour, let minutes = components.minute else {return ""}

    switch days {
    case 366...:
        return "\(days/365) years ago"
    case 7...:
        return "\(days/7) \(days/7 == 1 ? "week" : "weeks") ago"
    case 1...:
        return "\(days) \(days == 1 ? "day" : "days") ago"
    default:
        if hours > 0 {
            return "\(hours) \(hours == 1 ? "hour" : "hours") ago"
        }else if minutes > 0 {
            return "\(minutes) \(minutes == 1 ? "minute" : "minutes") ago"
        }else{
            return "now"
        }
    }

}

timeSinceNowString(1532194221795) // "3 weeks ago"
```

Comment: Thank you! that works for that error. I'm still getting "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error on this line of code let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self, to: Date())

Comment: What instance 'self' refer to?